# Create NSMenu for NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I'm trying to create a simple menu in the System Status Bar using code only.  I'm not receiving any compilation or runtime errors but I see no effect at all.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSMenu *stackMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status Menu"];
    NSMenuItem *soMenuItem = 
        [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status Menu Item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@"S"];
    [soMenuItem setEnabled:YES];
    [stackMenu addItem:soMenuItem];
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
                   statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]
                  retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:stackMenu];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe the `NSStatusItem` will implicitly take on the `title` of the `NSMenu` associated with it (which is what I am guessing you want to happen.)  Try explicitly setting the `NSStatusItem`'s `title` (and/or its `image`).

e.x.

```
[statusItem setTitle:[stackMenu title]];
```

Comment: Or its `view`. (And yes, this is definitely the reason you'd not see anything with the OP code.)

Comment: Just figured this out before refreshing the page.  Thanks!